# How do i calculate probability for the following?

Tags: probability

Suppose a new cancer treatment has been discovered, claiming to increase the one-year survival rate for pancreatic cancer patients to 40%. In other words, the probability that a patient suffering from pancreatic cancer would survive for at least one year after receiving this treatment is 40%.

Suppose a  hospital is planning to use this treatment for its pancreatic cancer patients.

The hospital has a total of 10 patients suffering from pancreatic cancer. What is the probability that exactly 4 of these patients would survive the first year after receiving this treatment?

Comment: This is not a programming question and it smells like homework. You should look at the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Answer (score 1):

Its binomial probability distribution algorithm should be apply to find

so you have to apply the below formula

P(x=r) = ncr * (p)^r * (1-p)^(n-r)

p(x=4) = 10c4 * (0.4)^4 * (1-0.4) ^6

Ans : 0.250822656

Answer (score 0):

p=0.4,1-p=0.6,n=10,r=4

P(x=r)=nCr*P^r*(1-P)^n-r

P=10C4*(0.4)^4*(0.6)^6

ANSWER=0.251 or 25.1%

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.